# MongoDB stats shows weird stats

Tags: mongodb

Sry guys - i'm the total beginner with MongoDb. When i type "db.stats()" in the mongo shell i get following output:

```
{
    "db" : "test",
    "collections" : 0,
    "objects" : 0,
    "avgObjSize" : 0,
    "dataSize" : 0,
    "storageSize" : 0,
    "numExtents" : 0,
    "indexes" : 0,
    "indexSize" : 0,
    "fileSize" : 0,
    "nsSizeMB" : 0,
    "dataFileVersion" : {

    },
```

That is totally strange because disk space (about 500MB) is already occupied. So i know for sure, that there are collections. What am i doing wrong? (Sry if this is a total stupid question :( )

Comment: Maybe the collections are in a different database. Try show dbs; to see if there are other databases.

Comment: Lol. That was stupid! Works!Thanks!

Comment: I'll add it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the collections are in a different database. Try show dbs; to see if there are other databases.

Answer (score 2):

`db.stats()` will show the stats for the current database.

As mentioned in the comments, there may be other databases.

You can use  `show dbs` to show all databases, followed by

```
use <db-name>
db.stats()
```